# Can we Pass ClaimIndentity in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, claims-based-identity

I want to implement a scenario where, Presently in each method of my project, i am accessing the userId which i got from claims.

So instead of passing claim.UserId in every method, i want to implement a solution in such way that claims can initialised in service DI and it does not need to pass in every method so whenever the service initialise that claims could also get initialise same time.
for e.g

```
Service
{
  // something at here

method1{


}

method2{

}
}
```

please suggest me any doc or article or best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IHttpContextAccessor for it.

```
    public class ServiceWithUserId
    {
        private readonly Guid userId;
        private const string nameIdentifierType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";

        public ServiceWithUserId(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {

            userId = Guid.Parse(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identities.Single().Claims.Single(c => c.Type == nameIdentifierType).Value);
        }

        public void Method1()
        {
            if (userId == Guid.Empty)
            {
                // ...
            }

        }
    }
```

You also have to add IHttpContextAccessor into ServiceCollection.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```